# Is this the right way to set up Basic Authentication with Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, retrofit2, basic-authentication, okhttp

I'm doing a side project and all I know is I should use Basic Authentication. Since I don't have experience using it, I found some stuff online and I want to ask you for your opinion, is this the right way to do it...

So, first thing is from Retrofit's documentation:

This is the Retrofit(network) setup:

```
public class RetrofitSetup {

public static final String API_BASE_URL = "----";

private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
        new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

private static Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return createService(serviceClass, null, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(
        Class<S> serviceClass, String username, String password) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(username)
            && !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
        String authToken = Credentials.basic(username, password);
        return createService(serviceClass, authToken);
    }

    return createService(serviceClass, null);
}

public static <S> S createService(
        Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(authToken)) {
        AuthenticationInterceptor interceptor =
                new AuthenticationInterceptor(authToken);

        if (!httpClient.interceptors().contains(interceptor)) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);

            builder.client(httpClient.build());
            retrofit = builder.build();
        }
    }

    return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

}

And Authentication Interceptor:

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private String authToken;

public AuthenticationInterceptor(String token) {
    this.authToken = token;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request original = chain.request();

    Request.Builder builder = original.newBuilder()
            .header("Authorization", authToken);

    Request request = builder.build();
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
}
```

This is my RetrofitSerive class:

```
public interface RetrofitService {

@GET("login")
Call<Void> basicLogin();

@GET("contact")
Call<List<Contacts>> getContacts(@Header("Authorization") String authkey);

@GET("product")
Call<List<Products>> getProducts(@Header("Authorization") String authkey);

}
```

And the class I found online for generating auth key:

```
public class Helper {
public static String getAuthToken(String username, String password) {
    byte[] data = new byte[0];
    try {
        data = (username + ":" + password).getBytes("UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Failed to authenticate";
    }
    return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
}
```

And I believe there is nothing to be changed here... So first thing is to login (check authentication), here is the couple of stuff I want to know how to do right:

```
private void login(final String username, final String password) {
    RetrofitService loginService =
            RetrofitSetup.createService(RetrofitService.class, username, password);
    Call<Void> call = loginService.basicLogin();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Void> call, @NonNull Response<Void> response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                // user object available
                editor.putString("username", username);
                editor.putString("password", password);
                editor.apply();
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Void> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

If response is successfull, I save those credentials in SharedPreferences..

Next page shuld call another request, so I wonder if there is any difference if I send both username/password or auth key?

This is how I did it:

```
private void getContacts() {
    prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = prefs.getString("username", null);
    String password = prefs.getString("password", null);

    RetrofitService loginService =
            RetrofitSetup.createService(RetrofitService.class, Helper.getAuthToken(username, password));
    Call<List<Contacts>> call = loginService.getContacts(Helper.getAuthToken(username, password));
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Contacts>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Contacts>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Contacts>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                kontaktiAdapter.setKontakti(response.body());
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Contacts>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

So in this call, instead of sending username/password to RetrofitSetup.createService, I'm sending Helper.getAuthToken(username, password) with username and password from SharedPreferences.

Is this the right way to do this? If you exit the app, in login screen I'm checking if SharedPreferences contains username/password and try login with those parameteres.. If I want to log out, I clear those parameters from SharedPreferences so next time user opens the app, SharedPreferences won't contain them, so user won't be logged in, he/she would have to type those again...

What are your thoughts about this, is there anything I should do differently? 
Regards!

Answer (score 0):

This is so far the easiest method i have ever tried for "Basic Authentication".

Use the below code to generate the auth header (API/Repository class)

```
 var basic = Credentials.basic("YOUR_USERNAME", "YOUR_PASSWORD")
```

Pass this as header to the webservice call (API/Repository class)

```
 var retrofitCall = myWebservice.getNewsFeed(basic)
```

Add the basic header as parameter (Retrofit Webservice interface class)

```
 @GET("newsfeed/daily")
 fun getNewsFeed(@Header("Authorization") h1:String):Call<NewsFeedResponse>
```

Sorry, my code is in Kotlin, but can be easily translated to Java.